# Unable to set cookie from node server -> app

Tags: node.js, cookies, fetch

I'm trying to set an httpOnly cookie from my node.js api (localhost:3001) to work with my react client app (localhost:3000), everything I've tried so far results in no cookie being set in my browser. Some key factors about my setup:

#### Backend is node, running fastify, fastify-cookie & cors

```
// CORS
server.use(
    require('cors')({
        origin: ['https://localhost:3000'],
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true
    })
)

// Cookies
server.register(require('fastify-cookie'), {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
})

// Sending the cookie
reply
  .setCookie('token', token, {
    domain: 'localhost',
    path: '/',
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'lax',
    httpOnly: true
})
.send({ user })
```

#### Client is running https localhost in chrome, making api calls using fetch.

```
const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const req = await fetch(`${process.env.USERS_API_BASE}/users`, { credentials: 'include' })
    const res = await req.json()
    console.log(res)
}
```

#### Result

No cookie is ever set in my chrome application inspector, but it is sent to the browser from the server and looks correct.

`set-cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiaGVsbG9Ac2hhbi5kaWdpdGFsIiwiaWF0IjoxNjIwNDI1ODI0LCJleHAiOjE2MjA0Mjk0MjR9.S8eOQMtSBY85wlenuxjIGYNuk3Ec5cKQ87pAhmCvQ9w.nfRxGzq3IMFimC%2FSJeUH9Xl7bH%2FyXVprwK1NBYfur4k; Domain=localhost; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax`

`request.cookies` on the sever always returns a blank object `{}`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is a CORS error OR at least it is categorized as one..
you see the server seems to think you're making a cross-domain request..

If you log the **responce Headers** this is typically what you would see

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 20:43:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: name=value; expires=Sun, 20-May-2018 21:43:05 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.localHost
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localHost:8080
Vary: Origin
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

but when you are making a request you kinda send it like this

```
const res = await axios({ method: 'POST', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/login', data: { email, password } });
```

Do you see the problem **127.0.0.1 != http://localhost:8000** and that is the solution to your problem

In short Check the `Key=value` Pair of **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** on your response and Request the domain names should match else the cookie won't be set on the browser...

Here is a GitHub Issue [Link](https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/complete-node-bootcamp/issues/80) for this same problem

Comment: i see what you are saying, but i'm not using `127.0.0.1` to referr to anything. In the response from the request that sends the cookie I do see `Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3001`, but thats the only reference I can see to the IP version.

Comment: In that case on your server where you create and send the cookie you will need to change it to ```\`http://locahost:${PORT}`\```

Comment: @ShanRobertson Did you solve this?